# OSX default apache process can not run node commands in php

Tags: php, node.js, macos, apache, path

Apache user _www can not run commands such as 'node' in php code.

```
execWrap("node --version"); // end up with not known command

getenv('path'); // returned limited set of paths
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update:

```
sudo nano /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/org.apache.httpd.plist
```

Change:

```
<key>EnvironmentVariables</key>
    <dict>
    <key>PATH</key
   <string>/opt/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin:/usr/local/mysql/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/git/bin</string>
</dict>
```

And restart apache:

```
sudo apachectl restart
```